# Vue.js - Can't access computed properties from methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a login method inside a Vue component that uses firebase to sign in a user. I'm using computed properties `user`, `message`, and `hasErrors`. When this method runs, It goes into the `catch` function, but this error comes up: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'message' of undefined`. I've tried changing the vuex state directly (because that's what the computed prop does), but this gives the same error. Here is the method I'm using:

```
login: function (event) {
  // ... more stuff
  // Sign-in the user with the email and password
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
    .then(function (data) {
      this.user = firebase.auth().currentUser
    }).catch(function (error) {
      this.message = error.message
      this.hasErrors = true
    })
  // ...
}
```

Here's what the computed prop looks like:

```
message: {
  get () {
    return this.auth.message // mapState(['auth'])
  },
  set (value) {
    this.$store.commit('authMessage', value)
  }
}
```

I'm pretty sure the problem has to do with it being inside a `Promise`.
So how can I access computed properties within the firebase `Promise`?

Comment: `this` is not what you think it is inside the callback-probably want to read up on how `this` works, and how to remedy it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`this` inside a callback refers to the callback itself (or rather, as pointed out, the execution context of the callback), not the Vue instance. If you want to access `this` you either need to assign it to something outside the callback:

```
  // Assign this to self
  var self = this;

  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
    .then(function (data) {
      self.user = firebase.auth().currentUser
    }).catch(function (error) {
      self.message = error.message
      self.hasErrors = true
    })
```

Or if you are using ES2015 use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which do not define their own `this` context:

```
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
    .then(data => {
      this.user = firebase.auth().currentUser
    }).catch(error => {
      this.message = error.message
      this.hasErrors = true
    })
```

Comment: It doesn't refer to the callback, it refers to the execution context of the callback, whatever that might be.

Comment: Yes, I knew I would get that response from somebody as soon as I typed it. ;)